# Net flux through surface

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

[image]

if equal number of electric field enters and equal leaves. Then why isnt net flux zero?

Comment: If you are talking about closed surface then net flux is 0 as far as I remember.

Comment: The net flux is zero

Comment: but the answer key says the net flux through the curved area is E.ℼr^2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electric flux through an area is defined as the electric field multiplied by the area of the surface projected in a plane perpendicular to the field. See the diagram below and equation below for calculating the net flux over a closed surface.

If the electric field lines are straight equally spaced parallel lines, as shown in your diagram, $\vec E$ is constant and comes out of integral. Integrating over the bottom (circular) surface of your diagram the flux is

$$\phi_{bottom}=-\pi r^{2} E$$

The flux is negative because $\cos 180 =-1$.

For the hemispherical surface, the area of the surface projected in a plane perpendicular to the field is the circular area below, or $\pi r^2$. The electric flux is then the electric field times that area or

$$\phi_{top}=+\pi r^{2} E$$

The flux is positive since $\theta$ between the field and the projected surface is zero.
Then the net flux over the entire closed surface becomes

$$\phi_{E}=\phi_{top}+\phi_{botton}=0$$

It should be noted that the net flux for a closed surface will always be zero unless electric field lines either originate or terminate in the space enclosed by the surface. That will only occur if there is net charge enclosed by the surface. Then the net electrical flux for any closed surface will be, per Gauss' Law, the net charge enclosed by the surface divided by the electrical permittivity of the enclosed space, or, for free space,

$$\phi_{E}=\frac{Q}{\epsilon_{o}}$$

Hope this helps

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand the flux , if you put a surface like the lens in a river letting the water trough, you would agree that the flow or flux of the water is not zero. Its exactly the amount of water or E going through wich makes the flow or flux.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a sphere and there's charge distributed to that sphere. So now I want to calculate flux of that sphere.

$$\phi = \oint_S \vec E \cdot d\vec a$$
It is surface integral if electric field is perpendicular to that surface then flux is definitely $0$ since dot product of them is $\cos \theta$ if $\theta$ is $π/2$ then the answer will be zero no what surface you take. But now I want to work with charge distributed in that field.
$$\phi=\vec E \cdot \vec 4πr^2$$
Area of sphere is $4πr^2$. Let theta is zero. $$\phi=\frac{1}{4π\epsilon_0} \frac{q_{enc}}{r^2}$$
$$=\frac{q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0$$

If net charge in that field is $0$ then the flux will be also zero.

Note :electric field in any closed surface is $0$ since electric field is perpendicular to the surface but It's not always true for open surface but if you add all the surfaces flux then you will get $0$ (which is also closed surface )